# Using Number sequence in PaymentRef field in AR302000 screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use this PHIEUTHU sequence in AR302000 Payment and application screen to 
[image]

auto fill in ExtRefNbr text field
[image]

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    protected void ARPayment_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
  base.ARPayment_RowPersisting(sender, e);
  //var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
  if (this.IsImport)
    {
      if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert)
        {
            String numbering = ARSetup.Current.ExtRefNbr;
            Boolean autonumber = true;
            if (numbering != null)
               {
                 Numbering num = PXSelect<Numbering, Where<Numbering.numberingID, Equal<Required<Numbering.numberingID>>>>.Select(this, numbering);
                 if (num != null && num.UserNumbering == true)
                   {
                     autonumber = false;
                   }

      }}

}

    var payment = (ARPayment)e.Row;
    if (autonumber == false)
      {
        AutoNumberAttribute.SetNumberingId<APPayment.refNbr>(this.Document.Cache, payment.DocType, numbering);
      }
```

}

[image]
Here is the error:

> \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(33): error CS0117:
>   'PX.Data.PXGraphExtension' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ARPayment_RowPersisting'
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(33): error CS0103: The name
>   'sender' does not exist in the current context
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(35): error CS1061:
>   'PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry_Extension' does not contain a definition
>   for 'IsImport' and no extension method 'IsImport' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry_Extension' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(39): error CS0117:
>   'PX.Objects.AR.ARSetup' does not contain a definition for 'Current'
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(43): error CS0120: An object
>   reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
>   'PX.Data.PXSelectBase.Select(params
>   object[])' \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(54): error CS0103: The
>   name 'autonumber' does not exist in the current context
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(56): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'APPayment' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(56): error CS1061:
>   'PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry_Extension' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Document' and no extension method 'Document' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry_Extension' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(56): error CS0103: The name
>   'numbering' does not exist in the current context
>   \App_RuntimeCode\ARPaymentEntry.cs(33): error CS0117:
>   'PX.Data.PXGraphExtension' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ARPayment_RowPersisting'

[image]

My uploade included pictures, please take a look!
Help me with step by step please, I'm newbie.
Thank for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

If using a graph extension you will use "Base" as your call to the base graph and not base. When extending the events you can use the row delegate like this to call the base call. The example should work regardless if a base call exists in the base graph or not.

```
public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARPaymentEntry>
{
    protected virtual void ARPayment_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting del)
    {
        // base call...
        del?.Invoke(cache, e);

        // extended logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean the code gonna be like this right ? Mr Branden:  protected void ARPayment_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting del)
    {
      base.ARPayment_RowPersisting(sender, e);
      //var row = (ARPayment)e.Row;
      del?.Invoke(cache, e);
      if (this.IsImport)
        {
          if ((e.Operation & PXDBOperation.Command) == PXDBOperation.Insert) ...

Comment: i don't think the logic was your issues as much as it was the use of the extension and your base graph. What you have looks good from what I can see in the comment but you just need to include your logic where i have // extended logic which it looks like you did. are you still having issues/errors?

Comment: unfortunately I still had errors. It happen in line :"del?.Invoke(cache, e);" The error is: " CS1525: Invalid expression term '.' ", " CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected " and repeat the error " CS1525: Invalid expression term '.' " again.

Comment: you could be using an older .net version. just change the call to the delegate by first checking for null, then calling it...   if(del != null){ del(cache, e);}